# What would be the properties of an anti-black hole (concentration of negative mass)?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, mass, hawking-radiation

What would be the properties of an anti-black hole (concentration of negative mass)? Would it emit radiation? Would time go infinitely fast on its surface?

Comment: I believe the Schwarzschild geometry with a negative mass is perturbatively unstable, though I don't have reference to hand, so a negative matter black hole can't exist.

Comment: Besides  antimatter still has positive mass and the no hair theorem implies no difference between black holes made of matter or antimatter

Comment: @Lewis Miller this question has nothing to do with antimatter

Comment: Perhaps you should just call it a black hole with negative mass to avoid confusion.

Comment: @John Rennie would not it be like AdS spacetime?

Comment: @Lewis Miller Black hole is attractive while this one would be repulsive.

Comment: I struggle to see why it should be anything like AdS. The Schwarzschild solution is a vacuum solution while AdS is not.

Comment: A naive application of the formula for the Schwarzschild radius gives a negative radius. That *could* indicate that a BH with negative mass is unphysical, but maybe it just means that the usual Schwarzschild metric doesn't apply.

Comment: @PM 2Ring negative radius may mean there is an event horizon but it is repulsive.

Comment: @John Rennie AdS supposedly has repulsive horizon

Comment: Yes, you said that earlier. That's a reasonable guess, but guesses are often unreliable in GR. ;) You need to support guesses with actual calculations.

Comment: @JohnRennie: *I believe the Schwarzschild geometry with a negative mass is perturbatively unstable …* Here is a reference: “Instability of the negative mass Schwarzschild naked singularity”, [gr-qc/0604021](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0604021)

Comment: @A.V.S. thanks :-) I knew I'd seen it somewhere!

Comment: Wouldn't the counterpart to the OP be something like the *interior* Schwarzschild solution with a negative density? I assume one can just try deriving it with a stress-energy tensor with opposite sign $T^{00}$. Then the outside would by Birkhoff's theorem be a normal (perhaps negative mass) Schwarzschild solution glued on.